# Symfony2 and Twig form rendering in if - else condition

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

In my Symfony 2 app I got the following code rendering the form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_errors(form) }}
  <div class="form-group">
     {{ form_label(form.title) }}
     {{ form_widget(form.title) }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     {{ form_label(form.message) }}
     {{ form_widget(form.message) }}
  </div>
  {% if extras == true %} //this block should be rendered only if extras var is true
    <div class="form-group">
       {{ form_label(form.description) }}
       {{ form_widget(form.description) }}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The problem is that I get rendered {{ form_widget(form.description) }} even if my extras var is false, not with all other form fields but somewhere at the bottom of the form which is obviously a bug. How to make it render only if extras is true and disappear completely from the page in case extras is false?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All other form fields are automatically added to the end of your form by default. It triggers `{{ form_rest() }}` by default. Use this code to prevent this behavior:

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables

Comment: It works, thank you. Btw, it leaves empty space at the bottom of the form where it rendered undesirable form fields earlier. Dont you know how to fix that also?